# Completeness in Bloch states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hilbert-space, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

We know from the Bloch theorem that, in a periodic potential, the eigen wave functions are $\Phi_{kn}(r) = e^{ikr} u_{kn}(r)$ where n is the band index. So the solution can be expanded by them. Further, we can define a refined Hamiltonian $H(k)=e^{ikr}He^{-ikr}$ so that $H(k)u_{kn}=E_n(k)u_{kn}$

My question is that whether the wave functions $u_{kn}$s are complete for a any specific k, which means we can expand any periodic functions by $u_{kn}$s by any fixed k? Is there any mathematical principals that allow me to do that?

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723252/why-are-bloch-factor-orthogonal) help?

Comment: No,  your link is about orthogonality, which I fully understand. My question is about completeness.

Comment: Well, have you read the answer? The $\{u_{nk}\}_n$ build an orthonormal basis for a fixed $k$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(u)$, where $u$ denotes the unit cell...

Comment: I see, thanks for the link.