# Question about k.p Method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, material-science, electronic-band-theory

I am reading David Miller's quantum mechanics, and I do not understand the derivation for k.p method:

> We are particularly interested in the behavior of semiconductors near to maxima and minima.
> Though the calculation of the complete band structure is a difficult task, it is possible to
> construct simple, semi-empirical models useful near band minima and maxima. The
> k p. method is one useful approach to such models. It allows us to calculate how properties
> change near to those maxima and minima, and allows us to relate various different phenomena,
> such as band gap energies, effective masses, and optical absorption strengths. Once we have
> used the k p. method to derive an appropriate model, only a few measurable parameters are
> required to define the most useful properties of the band structure.
> We start by substituting the Bloch form, Eq. $(8.20)$, into the Schrödinger equation, Eq. $(8.3)$.

> $$\hat {H_0} \psi(r) = E \psi(r)      \tag{8.3}$$
> $$\psi(r+a)=u(k)\,\exp(ik.r)             \tag{8.20}$$
> We have $$[\hat {H_0} + \frac {\hbar} { m } k.\hat {p} ]u_{nk}(r) = [E_n(k)- \frac {\hbar^2 k^2} { 2m }]u_{nk}(r)  \tag{8.61}$$
> and at $k=0$, $$\hat {H_0}u_{n0}(r)=E_n(0)u_{n0}(r)\tag {8.63}$$
> Now comes a key step in this approach to band structure. Because the $u_{nk}(r)$ are the solutions
> to an eigenequation, Eq. (8.63), they form a complete set for describing unit cell functions, and
> so we can, if we wish, expand the $u_{nk}(r)$ in them, i.e.,
> $$u_{nk}(r)=\sum a_{nn'k} u_{n'0}(r)\tag{8.64}$$

The $u_{n0}(r)$ being the eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian $H_0$ would only indicate that it forms an complete basis set. However, $u_{nk}(r)$ is not a solution of Schrodinger equation, and instead it is just the periodic part of a Bloch function with the exponential part gone missing. If so, why is it that the function can still be written in the expansion form of (8.64)?

Comment: Use MathJax and the quote function, not screenshots (for text and equations)

Comment: I cannot understand what is it that made you think my question is not specific enough. Please specify. @TobiasFünke

Comment: I've edited my comment - sorry, I did not see the very last paragraph. Despite that, the rest of my comment still holds and you should really edit the question. Moreover, you should say why you think you cannot expand a vector in a complete basis...

Comment: Ok. I've edited my post.

Comment: Because in my opinion, $u_{nk}(r)$ are not vectors in the solution space, only $\psi_{nk}(r)$ are. The $u_{nk}(r)$ is just a composite part of $\psi_{nk}(r) = u_{nk}(r) exp(ikx)$ . That $u_{n0}(r)$ are eigenfunctions of $\hat{H_0}$ only means that $\psi_{nk}(r)$ can be expanded as their linear combination, not $u_{nk}(r)$

Comment: I think in eq. 8.63 you have a typo, it should read e.g. $u_{n0}$ instead of $u_{nk}$, no? Anyways, the author argues that 8.63 is an eigenvalue problem and the eigenfunctions can be chosen, due to the fact that $H_0$ is self-adjoint, to be a complete orthonormal basis for the space of functions on the unit cell. So you can expand any function of the unit cell into this basis. All of this can be made rigorous, of course with some more work and precise conditions. See for example [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/723252/why-are-bloch-factor-orthogonal) and the links therein.

Answer (score 0):

When $\vec{k} = 0$, $\psi_{n,\vec{k}}(\vec{x}) = e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}u_{n\vec{k}}(\vec{x})$ becomes $\psi_{n,0}(\vec{x}) = u_{n, 0}(\vec{x})$. Therefore, $u_{n, 0}$ indeed are the energy eigen functions .